# How to structure the PHP files?

Tags: php

In order to avoid repeated coding in the page's elements like (header or sidebar), I have to include() them in the PHP main files... However, if both the header and the sidebar are including [functions.php] - for example - and are both included in multiple pages, then I will receive a "redeclared functions" error!

How can the structure be in PHP in order to avoid too much coding, and also use (include) the functions in those included pages?!

Comment: Consider using include_once() instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: You can include it in header only, sidebar will have included that page default from header as the main page is having both elements included.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla Would you declare this as an answer to this question, please?

Comment: @Sky7ure, added as an answer, Now it can be selected.

Comment: I would recommend looking into some template engine, like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), [Plates](http://platesphp.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include it in the header only, the sidebar will have included that page default from the header as the main page is having both elements included.
Simple!!!

Answer (score 2):

As your project becomes more complex, it will become impossible to find there is only one place that you can include a file.  So deciding that file `a.php` is included only in file `b.php` becomes unmanageable.  Especially if you start having files with things like a User class, where this is referenced from several other classes.

Consider using `require_once`, this will not only mean that it's only pulled into the code once, but that if the file isn't found it will produce a fatal error and stop, whereas `include_once` won't.

A common use of this would be to load the configuration or autoloading, a lot of my project files will have...

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
```

as the first lines of the script.

Comment: And that require_once will be stated in both the sidebar and the header, **for example?!**

Comment: `require_once` and `include_once` can be in every single file you reference it from (it could be in every file if you wanted to).  The main thing is that it will ensure that it is only ever loaded once.