# call to same file from diffrenet folders

Tags: php

I have `language file (lang.php)` that located in the root folder.

The problem is that i have 2 files that call function `print_pm_texts` and each of them located in a different folder

- 1 in the root and
- the second in the "/func".

because of that i can't use "`include` "lang.php". - When the file in the root folder call it than all ok, but the second file doesn't find it. when i change it to: "include `../lang.php` than the root file doesn't find the file and the second one does.

I also tried to write: `include "./lang.php"` but it doesn't work either...

*How can it be fix?*

Comment: Use a different `include()` in each file?  Use the fully qualified path to the included file?

Comment: Are you able to 'include' each of the distinct file paths in each file?

Comment: Look into the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ([src](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) variable, and use that to create the link to the file.

Comment: [have you tried googling using include with a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)? [here is another one, probably more relevant to your scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP include paths relative to the file or the calling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378814/are-php-include-paths-relative-to-the-file-or-the-calling-code)

Comment: A recent answer I posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067893/how-to-structure-the-php-files/46068112#46068112

Comment: I had a few problems with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when testing. As it is usually set by a browser request, it wasn't being set when I ran it through the CLI in phpunit.

Comment: You should always, always, always make paths relative to `__DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php)  and absolute path like

`require_once 'C:\Apache\htdocs\myProject\lang.php';`

Answer (score 0):

According to you, your directory structure is like below.

```
- Root
    - lang.php
    - firstfile.php
    -func/
       -secondfile.php
```

Now if you want to include `lang.php` in `firstfile.php` use below line.

```
include "lang.php";
```

If You want to include `lang.php` in `secondfile.php`, then use below line.

```
include "../lang.php";
```

Comment: your wrote the directory structure right. 
I have another file that contain function. One time the first file call the function and on another time the second file call the function. It's mean that "include" need to fit both ways

Comment: you wrote the structure  good. you just need to add new folder: "ajax/".  both file inside "ajax" and "firstfile.php"  call to file "secondfile.php". "secondfile.php" call to "land.php" which located in the root

Comment: is `ajax` folder is in `func/` folder or in `root` folder ?